# Why is html5 audio-related warning triggering jQuery Mobile page events

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, html5-audio

I have an audio/source setup on a jQuery mobile 'page'. In FF21 the `type = mp3` generates a warning in firebug.

```
//HTML
<source id   = 'for_mp3'        
        src  = ''           <!-- src is set dynamically --> 
        type = 'audio/mpeg'   
>
```

> //WARNING
>
> Specified "type" attribute of "audio/mpeg" is not supported. Load of
>   media resource failed. warning.

This warning seems to happen 4 times.
Today I discovered that this warning is somehow triggering jqm page events. So now I am getting 'pageinit' firing 4 times ... this is causing problems.

---

**EDIT:** *I should mention that I bind to pageinit events using **.one**(...) but they still fire multiple times*

Comment: Try `audio` tag instead of `source`. It shouldn't trigger any warnings.

Comment: omar ... I do use audio/source setup ... <audio><source ...mp3><source ...wav></source>

Comment: Oh, you're using source for multiple sources. Hmmm..this is weird.